# Please edit or flag credentials/API tokens and PII in questions

Tags: discussion

While there's only so much we can do to protect posters from their own mistakes, we do not want SFSE to be a locus of any type of data breach or bad-actor activity. If you see a post that contains any of these types of protected information:

- Salesforce credentials or access tokens
- API keys or tokens for third-party services
- Personally identifiable information from a production Salesforce org

please don't hesitate to question the inclusion of that information or have it removed.

If you are a user who has edit access, go right ahead and edit that token or credential out of the question. If you don't have edit access, flag the question for the moderators. Leave a comment on the question to remind the asker that they've compromised their system and need to revoke the disclosed credentials.

If you see what looks like real PII in a question, don't be shy about leaving a comment to confirm whether it is or is not actual user data. There are some great tools that generate real-looking fake data, but we definitely do not want posters to deliberately or accidentally disclose their users' protected information here.

Comment: Won't the original data be visible in post history? or mods can remove that too?

Comment: It will be visible in post history. We are able to perform a redaction to remove information from post history, but it's a rarely-used power that gets applied only in very egregious or damaging situations.